How to calculate the ripple current in the circuit?
I am designing a simple PCB that includes two buck converters for testing. In the past, I encountered issues with one of the converters (LMR51430XFDDCR datasheet), where voltage spikes during power-up caused the converter to fail. Based on recommendations, I've decided to add a 100µF electrolytic capacitor with an ESR of 200mΩ at the input of the converter to help mitigate these spikes. The capacitor is rated for 800mA, but I’m not sure how to calculate whether this rating is sufficient for the application. Also does the output current of the buck converter affect the ripple current in the input capacitor? In my current design, the converter outputs a small current, but I plan to use this design on a PCB that will draw around 3A. I'm concerned that while the design may work fine with the low current, the input capacitor might fail when implemented in a higher current application. Any guidance or resources that can help me determine if this capacitor rating is sufficient would be greatly appreciated!


In a buck convertor, you have an inductor that basically controls how much the current ripples in the inductor. The larger the inductor, the smaller the ripple. It is this ripple that flow mainly in the output capacitors. Together with the capacitor ESR will give you the output ripple. The average current is going to the load.

@Tyassin and if the capacitor is at the input of the converter(C5) how can we calculate the ripple? Or is the ripple current the same at the input as at the output of the buck converter?

I encourage you to look into Buck-converters, there you will also find formulas for suggested capacitance and ripple currents.
But the current ripple at the input and output is not the same. In the simplest case, the inductor forces the inductor current to be continuous with a ripple around the average current.
The input capacitors current however is always discontinuous. It will mostly look like a square wave with and increase in current when the inductor changes. This give an decrease in input voltage.  The voltage increase when the capacitor charges again. this give the input ripple.
